# jQuery/CSS - Add fixed to element on scroll and remove it when reach end of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the code that i have so far:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 120) {
        $("#FixedBox").addClass("fixed");
    } else {
        $("#FixedBox").removeClass("fixed");
    }
});
```

With this code when the page is scrolled with 120px it add the class `fixed` to the element with id `FixedBox`.

**What i want?**

The element with id `FixedBox` is contained in element with id `Content`. So when the page is scrolled with 120 px my script attaches `fixed` class to `FixedBox` which makes it fixed.

How can i remove that `fixed` class when `FixedBox` reaches the end of `Content` ?

Here is an image in example:

[image]

How i can achieve that?

I hope you can help me!

Comment: `$('#footer').offset()` might be helpful for that. Figure out where footer starts, the height of the window the height of FixedBox and calculate the point where your `.scroll(...)` needs to remove the fixed class

Comment: Can you form it as an answer to this question ?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a function which checks if the scroll height is in between the start and the end of the content and adds the class accordingly. This would even work if you have several blocks of content.

**[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kn43x18b/2/)** (3rd content box is the target)

HTML

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content" id="target">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content{
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.fixed{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  background: blue;
  display: block;
}
```

jQuery

```
var content = $('#target');
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var offset = content.offset();
    var height = content.height();
    if (offset.top <= scroll && scroll <= offset.top + height) {
      $('.box', content).addClass("fixed");
    } else {
      $('.box', content).removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the end of your content by finding its position by `$('#content').offset()` or `$('#footer').offset()` more in the [jQuery API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

When you calculate the height of your elements and positions you can figure out the top threshold where you need to remove the fixed class of the FixedBox. Keep in mind that you also need to alter the non-fixed position of your FixedBox when it returns to the DOM flow, else it will snap back to the starting position.

Comment: I have a question: When the fixed class is removed does the element will stop at place or it will be returned back to it's first position before it receives the fixed class ?

Answer (score 0):

`

```js
var maxScroll = 120 + document.getElementById('#content').offsetHeight;
 if (scroll >= 120 && scroll <= maxScroll) {
     $("#FixedBox").addClass("fixed");
 } else {
     $("#FixedBox").removeClass("fixed");
 }
```

You just need to get `#content` height.